# ERROR: compilation failed for package 'LDheatmap'

Tags: r, windows

I am trying to install LDheatmap R package but keep getting this error.

> devtools::install_github("SFUStatgen/LDheatmap", force = TRUE)
> Downloading GitHub repo SFUStatgen/LDheatmap@HEAD
> Skipping 1 packages not available: snpStats
> ── R CMD build ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
> ✔  checking for file 'C:\Users\vinit\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpUnSSwg\remotes4c44719014b9\SFUStatgen-LDheatmap-a727a02/DESCRIPTION' ...
> ─  preparing 'LDheatmap':
> ✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
> ─  cleaning src
> ─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
> ─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
> ─  looking to see if a 'data/datalist' file should be added
> ─  building 'LDheatmap_1.0-5.tar.gz'

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/vinit/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

- installing *source* package 'LDheatmap' ...
  ** using staged installation
  ** libs
  g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'C:/Users/vinit/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/Rcpp/include'   -I"c:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c GT_to_SnpMatrix.cpp -o GT_to_SnpMatrix.o
  /bin/sh: line 1: g++: command not found
  make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf:260: GT_to_SnpMatrix.o] Error 127
  ERROR: compilation failed for package 'LDheatmap'
- removing 'C:/Users/vinit/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/LDheatmap'
  Warning message:
  In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/vinit/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpUnSSwg/file4c443bb22ac4/LDheatmap_1.0-5.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: You need to have development tools installed. See https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools42/rtools.html

Comment: If anyone knows a good dupe for this, let me know.  I searched a bit but most of the answers I can find are about people who already have Rtools installed but are having trouble with paths etc.

Comment: Thanks but I overcome this error by installing 'LDheatmap' in basic R-gui (x64) application instead of R-studio.